# Set variable inside if statement not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have file1.txt and test.bat in the same folder.

Inside test.bat:

This works:

```
SET test=file1.txt
COPY %test% file2.txt
```

This does not work:

```
IF ""=="" (
SET test=file1.txt
COPY %test% file2.txt
)
```

Why?
The only difference is "if" statement.

Whats more interesting:

```
IF ""=="" (
COPY file1.txt file2.txt
)
```

works

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

IF ""=="" (
SET test=file1.txt
COPY !test! file2.txt
)
```

More about "enabledelayedexpansion":
https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html